# Why the code "RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]" initialises a 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, cs50, implicit-conversion

This code is from the CS50 course, pset4, the "Filters" task.
The concept is following:

1. open an image file (BMP)
2. read all pixels to a 2D array, where 1-st lvl is a height, and 2-nd lvl is a width

**The code is next:**

```
// height, width are image`s property
// RGBTRIPLE is an entity (struct) of a pixel

RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

...

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    // Read row into pixel array
    fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);

    ...
}
```

**I understand that:**

1. we create a pointer *image
2. we allocate enough memory for 2d array: `calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE))`

**But what** `(*image)[width]` **means? Shouldn't it be a pointer to the** `width` **length array? If so, why later we iterate through the image height and fill the** `width` **length array?**

One guy on Reddit wrote: "`RGBTRIPLE (*image)[width]` *declares that image is a pointer to one or more arrays*". And it starts making sense then. **But I can't get where this "...or more arrays" part?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

declares a pointer of the type `RGBTRIPLE(*)[width]` that is a pointer to an object of the type `RGBTRIPLE[width]`.

The call of calloc may be rewritten like

```
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE[width]));
```

provided that the compiler supports variable length arrays. That is in this call there is allocated `height` one-dimensiobal arrays of the type `RGBTRIPLE[width]` i.e a two-dimensional array.

Or you could even write

```
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc( 1, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE[height][width]));
```

To make it clear consider for example the declaration of a two-dimensional array.

```
RGBTRIPLE image[height][width];
```

then the array designator `image` used in expressions (with rare exceptions) is converted to pointer to its first element. The type of elements of the array is `RGBTRIPLE [width]`. So the type of a pointer to the first element of the array is `RGBTRIPLE ( * )[width]`.

As for this part

> But I can't get where this "...or more arrays" part?

then strictly speaking it is incorrect. A pointer can point to one object. But you can allocate an array and the returned pointer will point to the first element of the allocated array.

For example in this declaration

```
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

there are allocated height one-dimensional arrays where height can be any non-negative number including for example 1.

Comment: better `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, sizeof(*image));`

Comment: @Vlad Thanks for your help

Looks like I get it better now, but still not sure if my understanding is correct.
Can I say that:
1. First, we allocate the memory enough for a 2D array
2. Then, we create a pointer `image` that actually knows nothing about our 2D array and just hold the address of the first allocated byte in memory
3. Later, when we run a loop + `fread()`, the allocated memory will be filled with `RGBTRIPLE[width]` arrays
And that's how we get a 2D array?

So later we can use this pointer (first byte address) to ask "C" to give us `image[i][j]`, for example?

Comment: @NeMaksym Let's assume that you have a two-dimensional array int a[M][N];  then you can declare a [pointer to the first elements of the array like int ( *p )[N] = a; Using this pointer to the first element of the array and the pointer arithmetic you can access any "row" of the array using the expression p[i].

Comment: @NeMaksym For example in this call fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr); the expression image[i] yields i-th "row" of your dynamically allocated two-dimesnional array. In this call the one-dimensional array image[i] in turn is converted to pointer to its first element.